# Outlook asks me to enter area code when editing telephone numbers in contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, telephony

I’m keeping my Hotmail contacts synchronised with my phone. However if i try to edit the phone number in Outlook 2007 on my PC, i get the following dialog box:

[image]

Sorry for Polish language, this basically asks me to enter an area code and [trunk prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunk_prefix). The problem is, Poland has not had area codes since December 2005¹, so regardless of what i enter here, this will result in wrong numer being saved into Hotmail contacts.

How can i bypass this dialog and simply get Outlook to save the number into contacts exactly as entered?

---

¹Numbers in Poland are currently of the form `+48 xxxxxxxxx`. Since October 2009, you just enter all nine digits whether dialling from landline or mobile.

Comment: What happens if you leave it blank?  Will it accept a fill character that the phone will ignore (e.g., there is usually a character that pauses for a second to wait for a tone).

Comment: @fixer1234 Um, entering the “pause” character would make my mobile dial part of the number and then try to [touch-tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) the rest. This wouldn’t work. If i try to close the dialog, it reappears and i have to kill the Outlook process.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Control Panel
- Phone and Modem
- Set "Country/Region" to "International Freephone Service"

This disables the area code and carrier code edit boxes.

Then restart Outlook and retest.

[image]